# Some error in radio button list in c#

Tags: c#

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    RadioButtonList rad = new RadioButtonList();
    rad.ID = "rad" + i.ToString();
    lbl.Attributes.Add("runat", "Server");
    rad.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute");
    rad.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top] = top + 20 + "px";
    rad.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left] = "200px";
    rad.Attributes.Add("runat", "Server");
}
```

For example, I'm creating 10 RadioButtonLists by using code, named rad1 to rad10
I wan get rad(1) to rad(10).selectedItems from users...

`rad(i).selectItems` gives me an error. I want to get the selected item from rad1 to rad10. Example:

```
answer1 = rad1.selectItems.tostring();
answer2 = rad2.selectItems.tostring();
answer3 = rad3.selectItems.tostring();
answer4 = rad4.selectItems.tostring();
answer5 = rad5.selectItems.tostring();
answer6 = rad6.selectItems.tostring();
answer7 = rad7.selectItems.tostring();
answer8 = rad8.selectItems.tostring();
answer9 = rad9.selectItems.tostring();
answer10 = rad10.selectItems.tostring();
```

But I can't even specify `rad1.selecteditems`, it's giving me an error. it keep saying that rad(i) is not exist in the context

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: `"Some error"`, can you specify the error? Also, `"rad(i).selectItems gv me error"`. Your code is `rad1.selectItems` instead. What is the correct code? Side-note: `"gv"` is not a word, please don't chat on SO.

Comment: I think you need to create those elements before `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: @AndréSilva: in ASP.NET? `RadioButtonList` is a webforms only control.

Comment: its say rad(i) not exist in the context

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, I confused the name but in ASP.NET there is a "initializer" right? My guess is that he is creating after asp.net creates its server-side components. I don't know if I'm expressing myself correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioButtonList rad = new RadioButtonList();
```

You are naming all of your RadioButtonList objects with the same name;

You should create an `array` or `List` of RadioButtonLists

Comment: No he's not naming them the same. Look for the line where he sets the ID of the control.

Comment: Yes he is setting the IDs, but the actual objects are all named `rad`. So he will be unable to reference the objects the way he is attempting to do so.

Comment: then what can i do to identify the ID of the 10 radio button list??

Comment: So what if he names the object the same? As long as the ID is different, he can use the ID to find them again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use following expression to find a dynamic generated control:

```
RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)FindControl("rad1");
```